# Append a Laravel collection with another collection

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to append an Eloquent collection with another Eloquent collection in Laravel 5.3.

This is what I've done so far:

```
$entries = Entry::all();
$posts   = Post::all();

$entries->merge($posts);
```

I tried to use `merge()` as shown in the code above, but it seems that I'm stuck with this kind of problem (since some of them have the same `id` with the same value):

[Collection merge eating up some rows](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-42-collection-merge-eating-up-some-rows)

Any ideas?

Comment: What is stored inside the first collection? It's difficult to answer without any code

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Try to iterate the second collection and push each element onto the first collection. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-push

Comment: Do you need it to still be a collection?
If not you can do this:

array_merge($entries->all(), $posts->all());

Comment: @ad4s Hmm, it make sense, however it sounds a bit inefficient, what if i have more than 2 collections? is there any other alternative?

Comment: @NielsenMartinsGonçalves yes, I need to merge / combine them and in some cases, I need to manipulate them or sort them, let's say, sort them based `created_at` which I cannot do it in Eloquent query since models may share same contract but does not contain any relationship information among them, or it may completely different models

Comment: @tronic you can manipulate it as collection using `sort` methos or as array using [usort](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.usort.php). Do you have an example of what do you need to do? It seems that you want to make it generic, so I need to understand better.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For versions < 5.4 you can merge the two eloquent collections by resetting keys with toBase like this:

```
$mergedCollection = $entries->toBase()->merge($posts);
```

For versions >= 5.4 you can use `concat` as suggested by [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57011901/1835484).

Comment: this appear to be working, I'm sorry to add additional question, but what if I have 3 eloquent collections? let's say `$entries`, `$posts` and `$users`? do I need to call `toBase()` each time before merging another one? or just straight `merge()`?

Comment: I think you will have to call `toBase()` every time you want to merge into your current collection. But your best bet would be to try it out in a small prototype :)

Comment: merge overwrites values in the old collection to values of the new collection, if the keys are the same. It is not, what was asked. toBase is not solving the problem, because all it does is makes a duplicate of the initial collection.

Comment: I had to downvote, because `concat` is the right method for this case.

Comment: The original question was for laravel 5.3 which doesn't have the `concat` method, I updated my answer with some more information about versions and a link to the `concat` answer.

Answer (score 26):

I believe you may be looking for `concat()`. This will append one container to the end of another container, regardless of the keys of either.

```
$mergedCollection = $entries->concat($posts);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer because it really appends. It does destroy the keys, but that should be the point, otherwise merge is the tool to pick.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the link: [laravel7.X](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-merge)

```
$collection = collect(['Desk', 'Chair']);

$merged = $collection->merge(['Bookcase', 'Door']);

$merged->all();
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need to merge big_products and small_products:

```
$products = $bigProducts->values()->merge($smallProducts->values());
```

> The merge method merges the given array or collection with the original collection. If a string key in the given items matches a string key in the original collection, the given items's value will overwrite the value in the original collection.

**But**

> **If the given items's keys are numeric, the values will be appended to the end of the collection:**

Thus, all you need is to get rid of keys and you can do it with `->values()` function.

Tested on Laravel-6

Comment: solves my problem, merging two different eloquent collections

Answer (score 0):

The merge() method receives an array, so you have to do something like

```
$entries->merge($posts->toArray());
```

[Laravel Collections: merge() method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-merge)

Comment: I got an error `Call to a member function getKey() on array`

Comment: Aparently you have to turn the Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection into a  Illuminate\Support\Collection: something like this:

`collect($entries)->merge($posts->toArray());`

 [more info here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9163)

Comment: You mean `$entries->merge($posts->all());`. `toArray` also changes your model attributes to an array.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me using a loop:

```
$collection= collect([]);
 foreach ($otherCollection as  $other)
 $collection= $collection->merge($other);
```